# Is TemplatePack<>...[I] allowed in C++26

Tags: c++, parameter-pack, c++26

[Pack indexing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pack_indexing) was introduced in C++26 and I was hoping for this feature to have a significant impact on metaprogramming stuff, especially for indexing packs which would otherwise require workarounds.

Since the syntax for pack indexing specifier is:

```
typedef-name ... [ expression ]
```

- where `typedef-name` is either `identifier` or `simple-template-id`

With the information above, does it allow to have like:

```
template <typename>
using apply_t = bool;

// #1
template <typename... Args>
using A = apply_t<Args>...[0];
// can be reworked with: apply_t<Args...[0]>

// #2
template <template <typename...> typename... Temps>
using B = Temps<>...[0]
// no other way other than this because 'Temps...[0]<>' is not allowed yet (?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**: while *typedef-name* includes *simple-template-id* as a grammar production, in this context it is required ([dcl.type.pack.index]/1) to name a pack (and `Temps<>` is not itself a pack).

Note that the [proposal](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/p2662r3.pdf) discusses indexing into template template parameter packs (and even new kinds of packs) as a future extension.